# Unexpected UserDict Behavior

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a project and need to make use of UserDict instead of dict.  I am importing a JSON file that is a dictionary with lists containing more dictionaries.

Here is some example code and the behavior differences I am seeing:

```
import json
from collections import UserDict
import pprint

person_string = '{"name" : "Bob", \
                  "age" : 25, \
                  "addresses":[{"city" : "Greenville", "state" : "NC" }, \
                               {"city" : "Whiteville", "state" : "NC" }]}'

# dict Example
person_dict = json.loads(person_string)
addresses = person_dict['addresses']
addr_1 = addresses[0]
print(addr_1)
print("\n")

# Add street to the first city entry
addr_1['street'] = "123 The Road"
print(addr_1)
print("\n")
pprint.pprint(person_dict)

print("\n")

# UserDict Example
person_user_dict = UserDict(json.loads(person_string))
user_addresses = person_user_dict['addresses']
user_addr_1 = UserDict(user_addresses[0])
print(user_addr_1)
print("\n")

# Add street to the first city entry
user_addr_1['street'] = "123 The Road"
print(user_addr_1)
print("\n")
pprint.pprint(person_user_dict)
```

The output:

```
# Dictionary Example
{'city': 'Greenville', 'state': 'NC'}

{'city': 'Greenville', 'state': 'NC', 'street': '123 The Road'}

{'name': 'Bob',
'age': 25,
'addresses': [{'city': 'Greenville', 'state': 'NC', 'street': '123 The Road'},
              {'city': 'Whiteville', 'state': 'NC'}]}

# UserDict Example
{'city': 'Greenville', 'state': 'NC'}

{'city': 'Greenville', 'state': 'NC', 'street': '123 The Road'}


{'name': 'Bob',
'age': 25,
'addresses': [{'city': 'Greenville', 'state': 'NC'},    <---- The 'street' is missing
               {'city': 'Whiteville', 'state': 'NC'}]}
```

Why did the new key not get added to person_user_dict and how can I get UserDict to behave the same way as a dictionary?

Comment: Because *you created a new dictionary here*: `user_addr_1 = UserDict(user_addresses[0])`, this isn't unexpected at all and would work exactly the same way if you did `user_addr_1 = dict(user_addresses[0])`

Comment: Assigning to `user_addresses` and `user_addr_1` doesn't replace the nested dictionaries in `person_user_dict` with `UserDict`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because *you created a new dictionary here*:

```
user_addr_1 = UserDict(user_addresses[0])
```

This isn't unexpected at all, indeed, this is how `dict` works. You would see the same exact behavior if you did:

```
user_addr_1 = dict(user_addresses[0])
```

You would need to recursively convert all the dict's to `UserDict` objects instead. But actually, you just want to use the `object_pairs_hook` for the json decoder:

```
In [3]: import json
   ...: from collections import UserDict
   ...:
   ...: person_string = '{"name" : "Bob", \
   ...:                   "age" : 25, \
   ...:                   "addresses":[{"city" : "Greenville", "state" : "NC" }, \
   ...:                                {"city" : "Whiteville", "state" : "NC" }]}'

In [4]: person_dict = json.loads(person_string, object_pairs_hook=UserDict)

In [5]: person_dict
Out[5]: {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'addresses': [{'city': 'Greenville', 'state': 'NC'}, {'city': 'Whiteville', 'state': 'NC'}]}

In [6]: type(person_dict)
Out[6]: collections.UserDict

In [7]: type(person_dict['addresses'][0])
Out[7]: collections.UserDict
```